# CSS :not() does not work on initial page load

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, accordion, pseudo-class

The following CSS rotates an SVG upward pointing arrow 180 degrees when the header does NOT have the .collapsed class:

```
.IRE-content__header:not(.collapsed) svg {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

But it does not seem to work when the page is first loaded, and none of the headers have the .collapsed CSS class. It only seems to work when the .collapsed class is removed.

This is for a bootstrap 4 accordion.

Comment: A bit of HTML wouldn't hurt here, or better still a [MCVE]

Comment: Are the SVGs being loaded from file or are they inline?

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements aren't rotated. Set your SVG to `display:inline-block`

Rough example:

```css
.IRE-content__header:not(.collapsed) svg {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="IRE-content__header collapsed"><svg viewBox="0 0 220 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Here the yellow rectangle is displayed -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="skyblue"></rect>
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="60" height="60" fill="yellow"></rect>

  
</svg></div>
<div class="IRE-content__header"><svg viewBox="0 0 220 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Here the yellow rectangle is displayed -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="skyblue"></rect>
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="60" height="60" fill="yellow"></rect>

  
</svg></div>
```